# craft 3 request

Tags: craft3, request

Can someone point me to the craft 3 docs where I can find informations about the request template function:

craft.app.request.getSegment(2)

I'm really struggling understanding the craft cms 3 docs...
Only found this:

this is deprecated:
https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-request.html

this contains the old and new functions names:
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#template-functions

thank you
Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the only documentation you will find for this in the section called "Changes in Craft3", then scroll down to "Template Functions" https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#template-functions

If you want a better explanation, go to the Craft 2 docs - conceptually the same, different syntax.https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/craft.request.html